# Non-abelian group of order $2n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am in the begining of studying abstract algebra and I ran into the following problem from Herstein's book:

For any $n>2$ construct a non-abelian group of order $2n$. (*Hint:*  imitate the relations in $S_3$.)

**My efforts:** I was trying to realize the meaning of hint but my efforts were unsuccesful. We know that $S_3$ is non abelian group and $S_3=\{e,\ \phi,\  \psi,\  \phi\circ \psi,\  \psi\circ \phi, \ \psi^2\},$ where $$\phi:\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\to \{x_2,x_1,x_3\} \quad \text{and} \quad \phi:\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\to \{x_2,x_3,x_1\}$$

But I do not  know how to apply the structure of $S_3$ with order  $3!=6$ to the group $G$ with order $2n$ .

Can anyone show the detailed answer, please?

I did not find anything useful in this site.

Comment: Here's a (hint at a) way to answer your question geometrically: study the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon. For $n=3$ you get $S_3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I did not understand your answer at all :(

Comment: The symmetries of an equilateral triangle are rotations and the reflections over the three axes of symmetry.. Write them down and write down the multiplication table. Look at the relations and convince yourself that the group is $S_3$. Now find and study the $8$ symmetries of the square.  I'm not prepared to "show a detailed answer" for you. Maybe someone else will, but then you won't have the fun of figuring it out for yourself.

Comment: @EthanBolker, Why are you considering the symmetry?

Comment: @RFZ  the reason why Ethan Bolker is considering symmetry is that is what groups are for.  The primary role of groups in mathematics is to represent the symmetries of something.

Comment: @fredgoodman, I suppose that right now this solution is quite difficult for me. Maybe i will omit it and will return when my knowledge in abstract algebra will be better :(

Comment: You may want to look up [Dihedral groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group). These groups are essentially the symmetries Ethan Bolker mentioned.

Comment: If by Herstein's book you mean *Topics in Algebra*, be aware that *many* of his exercises are hard to do with the limited information available up to that point in the book, but they become simple once you have a bit more knowledge.

Comment: @Bungo, thanks a lot for such excellent comment. Yes, i do solve that book and it is indeed good book however with difficult problems. What do you mean by "more knowledge"?

Comment: @RFZ I mean that in subsequent chapters/sections, Herstein will present material (theorems, examples, etc.) which are directly applicable to solving earlier problems. He does this intentionally as he believes that the student will better appreciate the subsequent material after struggling to prove things "directly" without the help of such theorems. I'm not sure I agree :-)

Comment: @RFZ it might be useful for you to consult my book, which is free online. Google my name.  But also bear in mind that the most important thing is to learn to get stuck and then get unstuck.  That means you have to learn to try things that won't work before you try something that will work.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034381/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-a-group-action-that-is-a-symmetry/2034397#2034397

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I take Herstein's hint to mean.

$S_3$ is generated by elements $\phi$ and $\psi$ satisfying the relations $\phi^2=1$, $\psi^3=1$ and $\psi\phi = \phi\psi^{-1}$. Herstein is quoted as writing: *Hint: imitate the relations in $S_3$.* This suggests that he intends you to examine a possible group generated by elements $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ satisfying $\Phi^2=1$, $\Psi^n=1$ and $\Psi\Phi = \Phi\Psi^{-1}$. Is there such a group? Does it have order $2n$? Is it noncommutative?

You already have clues to the answer, because in $S_3$, the group of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3\}$, you indicated that you know that the permutations $\phi = (1\;2)$ and and $\psi = (1\;2\;3)$ generate the group and (it can be checked that they) satisfy the relations. This might suggest to you that you try to check whether the permutations $\Phi, \Psi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ defined by $\Phi=(1\;2)$ and $\Psi=(1\;2\;\cdots\;n)$ generate a group satisfying the desired conditions.

It turns out that they do not satisfy the relations. Here is where the comments to the question come in. It is better to choose $\Phi=(1\;n)(2\;n-1)\cdots(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\;\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil)$ and $\Psi=(1\;2\;\cdots\;n)$. This choice looks a little weird, but if you label the vertices of a regular $n$-gon with the numbers $1, 2, \cdots, n$, then $\Psi$ represents a $2\pi/n$ rotation and $\Phi$ represents a reflection through some axis of symmetry.

---

**Could you demonstrate entire and detailed sokution?**

Since Fred Goodman already commented on your problem, let me direct you to [his algebra book](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~goodman/algebrabook.dir/book.2.6.pdf), which is free online. He writes about groups satisfying $\Phi^2=1$, $\Psi^n=1$ and $\Psi\Phi = \Phi\Psi^{-1}$ in Section 2.3.

Comment: Could you demonstrate entire and detailed sokution? It would be great

Comment: There are many entire and detailed solutions here on MSE. Start, say, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226505/understanding-the-dihedral-group).